# Which driver is enabled by default in Debian non-free image

Tags: debian, drivers

I would like to know which driver, free or non-free, is enabled by default for nvidia card or any other device that require proprietary drivers, after I install Debian non-free iso.

Like in Ubuntu, there is an additional drivers tab to check which driver (again, free or non-free) is being used.

Can this be done in Debian?

Comment: Not sure which drivers are installed by default if more than one driver exists, but all non-free packages are from separate non-free repositories and listed in the Synaptic package manager in their non-free sections. You can also list packages by "Origin" like "stable/non-free" or "bullseye-backports/non-free". The drivers-tab is Ubuntu specific.